# Apex Email: Html template

Tags: apex, email-template, apex-email-service

I am using the following code to send an email to user using HTML template. This issue which i am facing is i am getting email but the body of the email is blank. Am I doing any mistake in the code.

```
List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id,Subject, HtmlValue,Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =:'MyTemplate'];    
String subject = et.Subject;
subject = subject + ' '+ p.Name;
sendTo.add(p.Request__r.Reviewer__r.email);
sendEmailSet.setToAddresses(sendTo);
sendEmailSet.setSubject(subject);
String emailBody = et.HtmlValue;
emailBody = emailBody.replace('{!Request__c.Link}', URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +'/'+p.Id);
sendEmailSet.setHtmlBody(emailBody);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { sendEmailSet });
```

Comment: Is your template an HTML template?

Comment: @manjit_singh yes its HTML template.

Comment: Does `Name =:'MyTemplate'` work? I think the ":" is for referencing a variable, but you are already passing a hardcoded template name string. Can you do a debug on the emailBody string to see what it prints? Also, I don't see where `sendEmailSet` is defined.